# change seaborn pairplot legend alpha/color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
grid = sns.pairplot(data=vst_wgcna, hue='cluster', kind="reg",
                palette=palette, corner=True,
           plot_kws={ 'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.05}})

grid.map_offdiag(plot_unity,  plot_kws={ 'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.1}})
grid._legend.set_bbox_to_anchor((0.81, 0.5))
```

The legend have color dots before the “positive modules" and "negative modules", because I set alpha to 0.05, it is very hard to see. how to fix that?
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can remove current legend : `grid.legend._visible = False` and recreate a new matplotlib legend from scratch using `plt.legend`

Comment: You could loop through the legend handles and change their alpha `for handle in grid._legend.legendHandles: handle.set_alpha(0.7)`

Answer (score 1):

As JohanC commented, we can loop through the legend handles and change their alpha:

```
for handle in grid.legend.legendHandles:
    handle.set_alpha(0.7)
```